# Can ApolloProvider be made to provide to state instead of props?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-apollo

Redux's `Provider` component and `connect` function provide a reference to the store's state to wrapped components via `mapStateToProps`. As mentioned in the lovely article [How to Build a Redux](https://zapier.com/engineering/how-to-build-redux/), this is done so that you don't need to refer to a global store object or pass data endlessly down the DOM.

This has a great advantage: the store state is DOM agnostic. You can put any two elements anywhere on the page and provide them with any data you want from the store. If you have a form for customer search and a list of customer search results... the relationship of these presentational elements doesn't affect their access to data.

As far as I can tell, Apollo-react's `ApolloProvider` does not subscribe to this principle. When I wrap a component with a query using `graphql`, the results of that query are provided as props to the wrapped component. If those results are needed elsewhere in the app, they must be passed manually or stored on a global reference. In particular, props returned from a graphql query cannot be passed up the DOM.

Is there a way of making ApolloProvider "provide" query results to the rest of the app in the same way redux's Provider does? Do I need to build this functionality myself? Or, better yet, am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo uses Redux to cache the graphql query results.  Essentially if you have multiple components that need the same data, just use Apollo to wrap each of them with the same graphql query.  You can even go as far as defining the graphql connector once, and using that same connector to wrap your N components.

Comment: See, I hadn't thought of that! I'll definitely have to play with that to prove to myself that the caching works as advertised. If, for example, a query depends on variables passed in from mapStateToProps, is it the case that just one of them will fire and the rest use the cache?

Comment: This sounds a little like Re-frame's "subscriptions".

Comment: Hmm... also it seems possible to get at the store by using `state.apollo.data.ROOT_QUERY.customers` as ids into Apollo's data...

Comment: Hmm! Upon testing your suggestion, it works! But it is fragile: if the query in question takes variables, and if for any reason the different components are providing different variables, then the incorrect query is treated as a new separate query, fetched and added to the store. This seems like a risky move for your one source of truth.

Comment: If the query takes variables and the 2 components have props that produce different variables then each component will get data matching its props. That's a good thing and a useful use case. If you don't want that then you need to make sure your components get the same props. Should not be hard if both components are getting their props from redux. You'd end up with a `connect(...)(graphql(...)(Component))` chain to get variables from redux to pass to the graphql query.